# Tint color for CarPlay UI

Tags: ios, carplay

Is there a way to change the global (or for separate UI elements) tint color for CarPlay UI? I can't find any information about this.

I'm trying:

```
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                              didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    templateApplicationScene.carWindow.tintColor = myColor
    ...
}
```

but it has no effect, at least in my simulator.

Comment: not working now, but best bet for future would be to define an AccentColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of theming a CarPlay application as of iOS 15.4